# Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, liferay

I'm building an portlet service for Liferay using intellij Idea, but I am strugling in importing a module made by gradle as dependency management

the exption is

```
Build file 'G:\Projets\[...]\build.gradle' line: 2

A problem occurred evaluating project ':xxx-service-api'.
> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [{group=com.liferay, name=com.liferay.petra.lang, version=5.2.1}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly   group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.petra.lang", version: "5.2.1"
    compileOnly   group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.petra.string", version: "5.3.4"
    compileOnly   group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.aop.api", version: "3.0.5"
    compileOnly   group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "13.0.0"
    compileOnly   group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.annotation.versioning", version: "1.1.2"
    compileOnly   group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.core", version: "6.0.0"
    compileOnly   group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations", version: "1.5.1"
    compileOnly   group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: "8.1.0"
    compileOnly   group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "3.0.1"
    compileOnly   group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-api", version: "1.7.2"
}
```

Im using gradle **5.6.4** and liferay **dxp-7.4**

Comment: Are you running pure gradle, or within a Liferay Workspace? E.g. you could dramatically simplify your dependency management - especially with regards to those versions - with Liferay Workspace.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DXP, but from the Gradle's point of view that looks like valid code. Would you be able to share a reproducer Project?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you apply the Java plugin if you want to use `compileOnly`.

```
plugins {
    id('java')
}
```

Comment: Thanks @simon-jacobs, as sugest I add java as plugin in my build.gradle but I'm getting the same error

Comment: Hello, Thank all for your feedbacks, I resolve the issues by applying Java-library as follow : `apply plugin: 'java-library'` in my build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

If it is a new project, I propose you create a Liferay workspace using the Blace CLI `blade init -v [Liferay version] [workspace name]` and also use the CLI for creating your modules `blade create`.

The dependency management will be handled by the default configuration in the CLI and will look a bit like this:

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.dxp.api"
```

You might get around your issue by using this package manually as it contains all the code currently in your dependencies (and more)

Even if it is an existing project, you can create a new workspace and copy the configuration it generates.

Another issue can be that your repositories are not defined correctly, so your dependencies cannot be found anyway.

```
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
        }

        maven {
            url "https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
        }
    }
```

**Sources**:

- https://learn.liferay.com/w/dxp/building-applications/tooling/liferay-workspace/creating-a-liferay-workspace
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/liferay/portal/release.dxp.api/